# How can I test arbitrary routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, routes

I'd like to write a Rails functional test for a non-RESTful route.

I'm using Test::Unit.

In `routes.rb` I have this route...

```
match '/contract_search' => 'contracts#contract_search', \
    :as => 'contract_search', \
    :via => :post
```

And in my Contracts controller I have this action...

```
def contract_search
  # ...
end
```

In `contracts_controller_test.rb` I tried...

```
test 'POST to contracts with search params.' do
  post(:contract_search, {
    :contract_search => {
      :title_like => 'System'
    }
  }, unprivileged_internal_user_session_vars, { })

  assert(
    assigns(:contracts).length == 6,
    "@contracts.length #{assigns(:contracts).length} is incorrect."
  )

end
```

The action works as expected in the browser.

But the test just errors out with...

```
  1) Error:
test_POST_to_contracts_with_search_params.(ContractsControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
    test/functional/contracts_controller_test.rb:49:in `block in <class:ContractsControllerTest>'
```

My sense is that the Test::Unit is trying to post to `/contracts/contract_search`, I think.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your test code you are using `assigns(:contracts)`, You must make sure that your controller method is populating the `@contracts` variable properly.

May be you have missed some prerequisite to run the test case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with routing, it's with the `assigns(:contracts)` in your assertion. `assigns(:contracts)` is nil and so when you call `length` on it it returns a `NoMethodError`.

The answer must be in your `contract_search` action, can you post the code?